# Should a chatroom allow an outsider to decide what's appropriate and what is not?

Tags: discussion, chat

From my observation, each chatroom has its own personality. Just like different communities have different characteristics.

Personally, I find it absurd to allow an outsider to decide what is appropriate for a chatroom and what's not. And even if you are a regular in a community comprised of 100 people, your vote would only weigh 1/100. A community that consists of adults should be self-regulating: each member is entitled to his/her own opinion, and the community should be run by rules that balance all those opinions. It is like chucking many pieces of rocks into a container and shaking the container for a few minutes. Eventually the rocks rest in a stable position - it is called equilibrium.

Of course, there should be a boundary to what a community could be allowed to do - and the rule is generally not causing harm to other communities or people. Once in a blue moon, that line is crossed and a regulator steps in to solve the issue; that is expected.

However it is not appropriate for someone who doesn't even frequent the room to step in and say "hey your chatroom should be called this" or "hey you should not be doing that".

IMO, a chatroom on Stack Overflow has many purposes. One of them is to retain active users by providing an interesting environment for them to hang out in. Very few people like to help others all the times without getting paid for it, but we do it out of good will, because we like to show off our skills or maybe return kindness we have once been given. But that is what the main Stack Overflow site is for - we help others out when we want to do so, not when a question is dumped on us whenever someone is too lazy to do his/her own research. A chatroom might also serve as place where a few experts on the language want to have an in-depth discussion on certain features of a language, even if it only happens occasionally.

Comment: When the chatroom title is used everywhere else on Stack Overflow, you are no longer just within your community.

Comment: There are far too many assumptions in there regarding people being adults (as if that is somehow a guarantee for acceptable behaviour to begin with) and everything balancing out in the end.

Comment: Also, you're still being hosted. There is no dedication to whatever freedoms or nefarious uses, not is it required. As Lightness aptly put it: we're all guests on Stack Exchange.

Comment: When you are part of a larger organization like Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange and the actions in chat come under scrutiny, then yes I would fully expect someone to step in and so should you.

Comment: **Moderator Note** stop with the endless rollback fighting it is non-constructive.  @chmod711telkitty If you feel that the content of that image needs it's own discussion then create a separate post.  That has nothing to do with your original topic.

Comment: I know that room has been a thorn in the side of some of meta's most active users for years, but it also has been one of the most popular rooms, and one populated by some people who contribute quite a lot to SO. I happen to think this is no coincidence. The room has its own culture, sometimes that culture leaks out of it, and a few times that has been unfortunate. That'd be no different from meta's culture then, if you allow for the fact that the culture is different.

Comment: @bluefeet if you don't reply to this I will revert the post back to show the image because it's relevant?

Comment: @chmod711telkitty Obviously you missed my point, if you plan to incorporate that image into your post then include some context as to why it is relevant to your original topic.  Adding a _remember this_ with a screenshot does not do that.

Comment: Oo, ok will do.

Comment: I think stackoverflow should stay on topic. One thing I hate is for example people proselytising their political or religious view in a website that is meant for sheer information sharing about a technical subject. I once learnt German and used a website that at one time was marred with people preaching Islam for example. That is not the goal of the a website for language learning. Same goes for stackoverflow I think.

Answer (score 39):

Stack Overflow chat is part of Stack Overflow.

As such, Stack Overflow moderators are not "outsiders", and they are entirely entitled — one may even say *required* — to act when Stack Overflow's policies and terms of use are being flagrantly violated.

So, the premise of your question is flawed.

Comment: +1 so many times. It's just common sense. How does a room that sniffs out entitlement from half a continent away, get represented by a troll on the basis of this very entitlement. It's such a stark contrast, that I don't even know whether it's funny.